# orbit controls with multiple cameras and viewports

Tags: canvas, camera, three.js, viewport, orbit

Can I have many cameras in my scene, analogous viewports and different orbit controls for each viewport/camera ?

Is this possible and how?

Thank you

Comment: You can have as many cameras as you like in your scene, did you wish to render them at the same time?

Comment: the problem is that I want to have mouse events controlling the orbit, but I can't do it because when I do something over a viepwort, the others are also affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to have some element in you html that is replicating your viewports.

For instance, if you have a viewport that covers the top half of the canvas, create a div that does the same.

And then, link this element to that particular control

Comment: great, I ll try that and get back to tell you.